# as3 Triggering events from an external source

Tags: actionscript-3, tcp, air, osc

I am building an AIR app that cues multiple swfs in a kind of playlist. I need the swfs to be called from an external system. I've tried receiving OSC msgs but the media server software running on the external machine will receive but not send OSC. Is there a better way to do this? I've not formatted raw TCP before, but that seems like the best option yeah?

EDIT:

I am using a Pandora's box media server on trade show floor... It is set up to run videos, map projections, and serve to a matrix of displays. It has the ability to send and receive msgs via various protocol. The main issue, being I've already written this app with OSC in mind, as it utilizes the tuio library pretty heavily. The pandora's box will not however send OSC. I am simply trying to find another way to receive TCP msgs in AS3. i.e. if they were to send "1" that would trigger SWF "1" and so on...

Comment: What media server are you talking about and why would you want to format TCP? Your question is a tad bit vague. Maybe elaborate a bit on what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: What does formatting raw TCP mean?

Comment: I am using a Pandora's box media server on trade show floor... It is set up to run videos, map projections, and serve to a matrix of displays. It has the ability to send and receive msgs via various protocol. The main issue, being I've already written this app with OSC in mind, as it utilizes the tuio library pretty heavily. The pandora's box will not however send OSC. I am simply trying to find another way to receive TCP msgs in AS3. i.e. if they were to send "1" that would trigger SWF "1" and so on...